# Unterminated dollar quote started at position

Tags: plpgsql, dbeaver

I have the sequent code in plpgsql rather it would be a function after having solved this problem :

```
    do 
$$
    declare
        ...
    begin
        for new_element in select * from json_array_elements(datajson)
        loop
            insert into entities (id, "attributes") values (default, (new_element->'attributes')::jsonb) returning id into new_element_id;
            raise notice 'new: %', new_element_id;
            for team_element in select * from json_array_elements((new_element->'team_accounts_reverse')::json)
            loop
                team_aspects := team_element->'aspects';
                team_account := team_element->'account';
                if not team_account::jsonb ? 'id' then 
                    insert into entities (id, "attributes") values (default, (team_account->'attributes')::jsonb) returning id into new_account_id;
                else
                    new_account_id := team_account->'id';
                end if;
                insert into junctions (source_id, target_id, aspects) values (new_account_id::uuid, new_element_id::uuid, team_aspects::jsonb);
            end loop;
            for attachment_element in select * from json_array_elements((new_element->'attachment_users_direct')::json)
            loop
                attachment_aspects := attachment_element->'aspects';
                attachment_file := attachment_element->'file';
                if not attachment_file::jsonb ? 'id' then 
                    insert into entities (id, "attributes") values (default, (attachment_file->'attributes')::jsonb) returning id into new_file_id;
                else
                    new_file_id := attachment_file -> 'id';
                end if; 
                insert into junctions (source_id, target_id, aspects) values (new_element_id::uuid, new_file_id::uuid, attachment_aspects::jsonb);
            end loop;
        end loop;
        commit;
end; 
$$ 
language plpgsql;
```

why pg throws me the `Unterminated dollar quote started at position 5 in SQL ...` error only after adding the second nested loop ?

Comment: The `...` in the `DECLARE` section is unhelpful obfuscation. Show your actual code and your version of Postgres. I see multiple errors on a quick glance - "unterminated dollar quote" not being one of them. Unbalanced `end loop`, illegal `commit`, missing variable declaration, ...

Answer (score 3):

Solved by substituting double `$` quote with `'`.

That means that I had to escape all the `'` in the code.